# Progress Bar for loading Activity or loading a button progress

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have an Activity which have `ArrayList` loading contents, and creating database on `onCreate()` that have more than 20-30 tables. So it takes 3 seconds to load the Activity before it getting displayed. I want to implant a progress bar for the processing of that Activity on start. So that the blank screen never appears and the screen is likely to be live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Idea is good to show progressbar to the user. But For display that you need to use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Always use AsyncTask for this type of time taking procedures. Its very easy to use. Create Class like following.

```
public class StoreDataToDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //Do all DB related Task Here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Do all DB related to task in doInBackground method. Call this class in onCreate like this

```
new StoreDataToDB().execute();
```

Instead of Progressbar view you can use [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) also.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working and now the application works nice.

Comment: do you have any method for implementing it on a button processing. i have a button thats loads data from database and it is also time taking. is this methods works on that too.? if yes then how to use this method on a button processing.?

Comment: if the same class you want to implement then just call new `StoreDataToDB().execute();` on button `onClickListener`. Or you can also create differentclass and call that on onClickListener.

Comment: Please click on the arrow near to my answer. so other will know this is working solution. @NishantSambyal